# How to access files in Emulator SD Card using File Explorer?

Tags: android, android-sdcard, ddms, android-file

I have written a file "myData.txt" to the emulator SD card, and I can find it in mnt/sdcard/download using file explorer.

Is there a way to check if I have written correctly to the file without reading it again in my Android program? How about images? What can I do to view the images written in an SD card?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using **Eclipse with ADT**:

In DDMS, on the "File Explorer" tab, there is a toolbar. There are 2 buttons on the left: arrow with disk (pull from device), and arrow with phone (push to device).

Select the file and then click "pull from device" to save the file on your HD.

[image: screenshot]

For more information, check the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html#using-ddms)

> Working with an emulator or device's file system
>
> DDMS provides a File Explorer tab that allows you to view, copy, and
>   delete files on the device. This feature is useful in examining files
>   that are created by your application or if you want to transfer files
>   to and from the device.
>
> To work with an emulator or device's file system:
>
> - In the Devices tab, select the emulator that you want to view the file system for.
> - To copy a file from the device, locate the file in the File Explorer and click the Pull file button.
> - To copy a file to the device, click the Push file button on the File Explorer tab.