# I am using Android studio I want to write local text file via emulator

Tags: android

I want to write text file in local pc via emulator and i have try a lot of way but not yet successes so i need help for any one who will recognized what my problem. below is my codes.
This code work without an error but working less.

```
public void WriteText() {
    EditText txt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtwrite);


    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("D:/File.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        fos.write(txt.getText().toString().getBytes());
        fos.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this,e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is ur problem ?

Comment: The emulator is like a separate computer, you can't write files on the host's operating system.

Comment: So, do you mean the file must be on the server?

Answer (score 3):

> **Definition of Emulator**

The Android SDK includes a mobile device emulator — a virtual mobile device that runs on your computer. The emulator lets you develop and test Android applications without using a physical device.

It's a virtual mobile device.which means an emulator is much like a mobile device.you can only create files inside it not in computer.

> **Use the following method to create a file in android**

Set permission in manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

  public void createFile(String sFileName, String sBody){
    try
    {
        File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Notes");
        if (!root.exists()) {
            root.mkdirs();
        }
        File gpxfile = new File(root, sFileName);
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile);
        writer.append(sBody);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
         e.printStackTrace();

    }
   }
```

For browsing the newly created file [How to access files in Emulator SD Card using File Explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924348/how-to-access-files-in-emulator-sd-card-using-file-explorer)

If you want to send data from android to a computer system take a look at http://www.pixelstech.net/article/1368328614-Android-socket-programming-example

Comment: Thank your for your help but steel i have problem when i submit i get this error "Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)". this problem i do not know why happen it because i have allowed permission manifest.xml. below is my manifest`s codes    

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mydev.filereadingdata" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application
    </application>
</manifest>

Comment: Thank you for your help but steel iget the following error.              "Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)"         i dot know why occur it because i have allowed permission in manifest.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mydev.filereadingdata" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application
    </application>
</manifest>

Comment: what worked for me, simply going to application settings and revoking the storage permission and then giving it again, worked for me

Answer (score 1):

You cannot save files from emulator to PC.
Because, Emulator is like a seperate device so it is not possible to create files on PC.
Instead of that, you can do like this work around.

**Create and save text file in your emulator storage**

```
public void WriteText() {
EditText txt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtwrite);


try {
    BufferedWriter fos = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +"/"+"File.txt"));
    fos.write(txt.getText().toString().trim());
    fos.close();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(this,e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }
}
```

Once you done with your file creation, you can easily pull the created file from emulator to your pc using **adb pull** command.

**ADB command**

> adb pull /sdcard/File.txt D:/

Dont forget to add following uses-permission in your manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Note: Give some space for your emulator SDcard when you create your emulator.

Comment: Steel this codes return the same error "Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)"

Comment: Check once with your real device if possible, and then check whether you getting error or not. @MakameSharif